# Is a transaction mixin size of 0 the same as not using ring signatures at all?

Tags: ring-signatures, ringsize

If I choose a mixin size of 0, is that the same as if ring signatures were not being used at all?

Answer (score 2):

All Monero transactions, for some time now, have a fixed ring size (currently 11), which you cannot change/override (even where legacy documentation suggests you can change, you can't).

So,

> If I choose a mixin size of 0

You can't.

> ...is that the same as if ring signatures were not being used at all?

It would be a ring size of one, thus pointless, but would still a ring signature. Again though, this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Extra spam for stupid length check.